# Pandas: Creating a loop that selects rows from excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, loops

I am trying to read a certain excel file that contains specific data and modify them as well. Although I am not able to create a loop that reads the first 3 rows and then reads rows based on a pattern. I would like to read initially row numbers 1,2,3 then 10,11,12 and so on. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance. Have a nice day!

```
import numpy 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel('My Excel File.xlsx')
for i, row in df.iterrows(0,156,3): 
    dfi = df.iloc[(i)].mean()
    df1 =1/(numpy.log10(dfi))
    print(df1)
```

[image]

Comment: Tip: if you use the 'sheet_name' argument in the read_excel() function, you can open a specific sheet.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the format the excel sheet has? (i.e. columns and rows). I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. What should dfi look like when it prints (expected output)?

Comment: I am trying to select the 1st,2nd,3rd row with all of the columns that they include and then create a loop as you suggested to apply my code for another group of rows as well (for example for rows 10,11,12) but I have to create a "step". I am expecting to receive a column or a row as output. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `DataFrame.read_excel` method has a parameter called `skiprows`, it can receive multiple types of data, `list`, `int`or `callable`. The latter being a function that would return `True` if the function should be skipped and `False` otherwise ([documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html))

In your case you did not describe the pattern on how rows are skipped, you said row 1,2,3 then 10,11,12. Assuming that you want to skip these specifics rows you can do:

```py
df = pd.read_excel('My Excel File.xlsx', skiprows=lambda x: (x+1) in [1,2,3,10,11,12])
```

Here I added `1` to `x`, `x` represents the index ( ~ line number) starting at 0.

Comment: Thank you a lot. That was exactly what I meant. I have changed my code. Although it still does not work properly. Pycharm suggests Union[float, Any]. To be completely honest I don't have a clue how I should continue because I am new to Python.

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using ?

Comment: I am using 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do something with every n consecutive rows every m rows. Why not use a condition on the iterable?

```
import numpy 
import pandas as pd 

n = 3
m = 9

df = pd.read_excel('My Excel File.xlsx')
for idx in range(1, len(df.index)-n, m): 
    wanted_df_slice = df.iloc[[idx:idx+n-1]]
    do_stuff(wanted_df_slice)
```

Edit: @arhr 's approach seems more elegant, as it uses a parameter that is meant precisely for that, and avoids adding a for loop.